# Bash -- find a list of files with more than 3 lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a directory of files and I want to find a list of files who has more than 2 lines.

I know I can use wc -l to test each file, but how do I wrap it up in bash?

Sorry for the newbie question, new to bash.

Comment: Just hint, "find /tmp/ -type f -exec wc -l {} +"

Comment: Do you want more than 3 lines (as your title suggests) or more than 2 lines (as the body of your question suggests)?

Comment: What about `wc -l * | sort -n`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use this `find` command:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c '[[ $(wc -l < "$1") -gt 2 ]] && echo "$1"' _ '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 17):

Using `xargs` and `awk`:

```
$ find . -type f | xargs wc -l | awk '$1 > 2'
```

If you are in a git repository and want to count only tracked files, you can use following command:

```
$ git ls-files | xargs wc -l | awk '$1 > 2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to the directory, where the files are and use the following command:

```
for i in $(ls);
do
    if [ `grep -c '' $i` -gt 2 ]; then 
        echo `wc -l $i`;
    fi;
done
```

This works, of course, also as one-line-statement ;)

This line iterates over each file and use grep on it to get the pure line count. wc -l gets the count, too, but the result includes the filename ... I don't know, if you could use the value for comparison, too ... but it does not matter: If the line amount is greater 2 (-gt 2), then `wc -l` $i will output the line count and the file name. If you only want to see the file name, then substitute `wc -l $i` with $i.

Of course, i did not check, if each entry is a file. You could do that before checking the line count.

UPDATE: Although using ls for parsing is not recommended, one can still use it. You just have to check in advance that your filenames don't contain newline (or other odd) signs.

Comment: Well, I did not know about that ... but then I must say: If someone gives files such names, it is just his/her own fault. Newline signs just don't belong into filenames Oo

If the thread creator has to deal with such "shit" produced by someone else, then I feel sorry for him/her.

@gniourf_gniourf Thanks for the hint, I wasn't aware of that. But at least you can check whether there are evil signs through using `ls -l`

Comment: It's not only about newlines in filenames, it's also about spaces and glob characters! for example your code fails for a file named `hello world` or for a file named `video[season1].mp3` if there's also a file named `videos.mp3`. Now, 3 things: 1. You're using an _antipattern_: that is, you're doing something wrong from the start, and the only way to fix it is to fight against the shell (e.g., using `set -f` and `IFS=$'\n'`, and yet this will still fail with filenames containing newlines). The cure is to use a glob: `for i in *; do`…

Comment: 2. So, you're using an _antipattern_… and it also spawns a subshell and forks an external process: so it's really inefficient; and the cure, to use `for i in *` is both _safe regarding any type of filename_ and _efficient_. 3. Regarding _If someone gives files such names, it is just his/her own fault. Newline signs just don't belong into filenames_: this is just plain false as a newline character is perfectly valid in a filename (the only characters that are not valid in filenames are slashes `/` and null bytes)…

Comment: … now, it's very easy to put a newline in a filename, at least by accident: you're doing `mv my_file 'hello world.mp3` and forget to close the single quote, then maybe type something else like `touch 'a b'` and there you have a filename with a newline! if you're a sysadmin, you know that these things occur every once in a while. If you use the _proper_ way of looping though the files (with `for i *`) you're just safe 100% of the time! and you're glad you're having a super robust command and this really frees your mind `:)`… **you don't even have to check the characters in the filenames!**

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command. It works fine:

```
**find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for file do if [ $(wc -l < "$file") -gt 3 ]; then echo "$file"; fi; done' sh {} +**
```