# Bash: find files in directory with less than n lines

Tags: bash

I have a directory with multiple files:

```
filename_10-1.txt
filename_10-2.txt
...
filename_10-1000.txt
filename_20-1.txt
filename_20-2.txt
...
filename_20-1000.txt
...
filename_600-1000.txt
```

I would like to list all files that have less lines than twice the first number in the file name (e.g. `filename_10-874` should have 20 lines (2*10  lines) and `filename_40-684` should have 80 lines (2*40 lines)).

**Approach**

Step 1: I am able to count the number of lines in a single file, e.g.:

```
wc -l filename_10-1.txt
```

Step 2: Find the number of lines in all files

```
for i in $(find filename_* -type f); 
    do wc -l $i; 
done
```

Step 3: List only the files that contain less lines than their file name states.

I stumbled upon this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327371/fast-way-to-delete-files-with-less-than-x-lines), however, I was unable to alter the code to suit my needs.

**Question**

How do I list all files that have less lines than a number in the file name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash -- find a list of files with more than 3 lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370890/bash-find-a-list-of-files-with-more-than-3-lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this script:

```
shopt -s extglob

for f in *.txt; do
   n="${f//@(*_|-*)}" # extract first number
   (( $(wc -l < "$f") < 2*$n )) && echo "$f" # list files with less lines than 2*$n
done
```

The extended glob syntax (`@(*_|-*)`) is explained in [this tutorial](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob). Here in this code `*_` removes all text till we get `_` and then `-*` removes all text after `-`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk to count the number of lines and print the filename if it exceeds a given number. With Gnu Awk you can do:

```
awk 'BEGINFILE { f=FILENAME; n=gsub(/^.*_/,"",f)*2 }
     (FNR == n) { nextfile }
     ENDFILE{ if (FNR < n) print FILENAME }' filename_*.txt
```